# Pass redirects to a bash script

Tags: bash

**Is it possible to pass redirection into a bash script?**

I've had this issue before and usually just worked round it by passing parameters and using them as file redirects in the appropriate places. In this case I had a cron line that was not working:

```
0 3 * * * /home/me/some.sh 2>&1 > /folder/I/cant/write/to.log
```

I found this [run-as-cron trick](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/213302/278031) to test the actual command (which calls `env -i <envs>`) e.g.

```
./run-as-cron /home/me/some.sh
```

... but I can't think of any way of **passing the redirection** into the script (or changing the script to allow it). Tried this:

```
./run-as-cron '/home/me/some.sh 2>&1 > /folder/I/cant/write/to.log'
/usr/bin/env: ‘/home/me/some.sh 2>&1 > /folder/I/cant/write/to.log’: No such file or directory
```

Which I kind of expected.

I feel like I'm fighting something fundamental in bash and it's hard to search as most places just explain bash redirection. I'd like to stop ignoring this when I meet it and either know it's not possible or have some more bash magic at my disposal.

Comment: It sounds like you want a "pipe" (`|`) instead of a "redirect" (`>`).  Or better, just have cron call a script that does everything you need.

Comment: Put `exec > /folder/I/cant/write/to.log` as a line in the script, if the script is run by a user who *does* have that write access.

Comment: However, since you aren't running `sudo` or anything else that changes privileges, I don't see why you expect having the script do the redirection itself would change anything. If the parent process doesn't have permissions to access the directory, and there's no privilege boundary between it and the child, the child won't have permission either.

Comment: `run-as-cron` (at least, the definition of it you linked to) only changes environment variable definitions. It doesn't change or fix anything about permissions.

Comment: The root problem is that arguments contain *data* (specifically strings), not shell syntax. Redirects are part of shell syntax, so you can't "pass" them as arguments. You can pass a `>` character, or a string containing it, but in order to pass it you need to get the shell to treat it as just a character in a string... which means it's just a character in a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
./run-as-cron "bash" "-c" "/home/me/some.sh >/folder/I/cant/write/to.log 2>&1"
```

Explanation:

a) `2>&1` redirection needs to come after file redirection

b) According to https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/42715/how-can-i-make-cron-run-a-job-right-now-for-testing-debugging-without-changing/213302#213302 , `run-as-cron.sh` is defined as

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/env -i $(cat /home/username/tmp/cron-env) "$@"
```

Because of the "$@", you need to pass your arguments as positional parameters. The `bash -c xxx` needs to be tokenized into three arguments.

Comment: Thanks, the bash -c trick worked. I've used that before, but didn't get it to work in this example. Does the environment stay the same as the enclosing environment as created by ```env -i```?

Comment: `env -i` creates a new empty  environment, independent of the environment from where it was called.